# SSH and Vagrant

Tags: macos, ssh, vagrant

When I run `vagrant up` in my app the process gets stuck at

```
SSH auth method: private key
```

Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.define :touch_rugby do |app_config| 
    app_config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
    app_config.vm.host_name = "touchrugby"
    app_config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "33.32.1.2"
    app_config.ssh.insert_key = true
  end
end
```

When running `vagrant ssh-config` in another window

```
HostName 127.0.0.1
User vagrant
Port 2222
UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
StrictHostKeyChecking no
PasswordAuthentication no
IdentityFile /Users/rich/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key
IdentitiesOnly yes
LogLevel FATAL
```

Where would the insecure_private_key come from? and should it not be a private_key?

What can I look at to try and debug this? I ran `vagrant up` in debug mode and found this

```
  INFO ssh: Attempting to connect to SSH...
  INFO ssh:   - Host: 127.0.0.1
  INFO ssh:   - Port: 2222
  INFO ssh:   - Username: vagrant
  INFO ssh:   - Password? false
  INFO ssh:   - Key Path: ["/Users/rich/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"]
  DEBUG ssh:   - connect_opts: {:auth_methods=> ["none "hostbased""publickey"],
                                :config=>false, 
                                :forward_agent=>false,
                                :send_env=>false,
                                :keys_only=>true,
                                :paranoid=>false,
                                :password=>nil,
                                :port=>2222,
                                :timeout=>15 }
 INFO subprocess: Starting process: ["/usr/local/bin/VBoxManage", "showvminfo", "1f000e35-eee4-482d-8f76-91082f19c2ab", "--machinereadable"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The private key that you see at `/Users/rich/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key` is generated by vagrant, if the `ssh.insert_key` property is set to true.

[Looking at the documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/ssh_settings.html), you should be able to specify the location to an existing private key using.

**config.ssh.private_key_path**

```
The path to the private key to use to SSH into the guest machine. By default this is the insecure private key that ships with Vagrant, since that is what public boxes use. If you make your own custom box with a custom SSH key, this should point to that private key.
```

Comment: i appreciate updated my question after your answer but i have `app_config.ssh.insert_key = true` in my config which should replace this key

Comment: I am not so sure I understand your question. By setting that to true, you tell vagrant to generate its own key.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, Vagrant will automatically use a public, "well-known" ssh key and will automatically set the virtual box up to use that key.  To get that behavior just don't set the `app_config.ssh.insert_key = true` option in your Vagrantfile.

We set these two options in our Vagrantfile because we don't use the default `vagrant` account but to better emulate our AWS environment we create an `ec2-user` account and specify our own private ssh key.

```
config.ssh.username = "ec2-user"
config.ssh.private_key_path = "/Users/lance/git/devops/.vagrant_helpers/vagrant_private_key"
```